# Does a stray \ [backslash] have any meaning in C code?

Tags: c

For the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    \
    printf("Test");
}
```

compiling via `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wfatal-errors test.c` doesn't give any warnings.

However for other stray characters, compiling leads to the following error:

```
test.c:3:1: error: stray ‘`’ in program
 `
 ^
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

I tried the same, with different stray characters, and each time I got an error. These errors ranged from *expected primary-expression before the token* to *value computed is not used*. I was expecting a similar warning/error for the backslash character as well.

So, does a stray backslash followed by no spaces have no meaning in C code?

I know for a fact that redundant semicolons (;) don't have any effect in C code, so are these somehow related?

Comment: @ThomasJager,  I am not using this in a define.

Comment: The define is just a particular example of its use. The question that I've marked as possible duplicatee asks about it in general, but gives the define as a particular example where it is usually found.

Comment: oh, I get it now, thanks @ThomasJager

Comment: It means end of the source line, but that's not what the warning is about. 

Stray `‘` suggests that copied the code from a pdf, or wrote it in MS Word etc, so that you ended up with something like `''Test''` and not a correct string literal like `"Test"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The backslash is escaping the newline that follows it.  It is used to logically combine two or more lines in cases where whitespace is relevant, such as in the middle of a string constant or as part of a macro definition so that it may span multiple lines.

In this particular case the whitespace is not significant so there is no effect on the code.

If you were to add spaces after the `\` you would get a warning, and if you put a `;` after those spaces you would get an error regarding a stray `\`.

Comment: I am not sure it is relevant anywhere other than macros. String literal can be split with a pair of `"`.

Comment: At what level? At the lexer level, so the compiler doesn't see it?

Answer (score 2):

It's the line continuation character. (You see it most often in macros.) The *trigraph* `??/` has the same effect.

If there was whitespace after it, then a compiler would issue a diagnostic.

Answer (score 0):

It splits a line so that continues on next line